# Madgwick IMU algorithm, how to get 360 degree freedom variables?

Tags: 3d, rotation, imu

I'm implementing different `IMU` methods in a project of mine and I'm currently experimenting with the well known [Madgwick's implementation of Mayhony's AHRS algorithm](http://www.x-io.co.uk/res/sw/madgwick_algorithm_c.zip) (MahonyAHRS.c)

So far it works around as good as my self implemented one which is based on Vector rotation and an running average sensor fusion (often called complementary).

However, I would like to get 360 degree of freedom out of it and I currently use this function:

```
void imu_mahony_getRollPitchYaw(float *roll_, float *pitch_, float *yaw_) 
{
    *yaw_ = fast_atan2f(2*q1*q2 - 2*q0*q3, 2*q0*q0 + 2*q1*q1 - 1); 
    *pitch_ = -asin(2*q1*q3 + 2*q0*q2); 
    *roll_ = atan2f(2*q2*q3 - 2*q0*q1, 2*q0*q0 + 2*q3*q3 - 1);
}
```

However, that results in the 90 degree issues.
What I would like is to receive pitch and roll in a form of 0-359 degrees.